# HTML SSE or PHP SSE .innerHTML display order

Tags: php, javascript, server-sent-events

I'm trying to have the newest messages pulled into the page on top. Currently the newest messages are going underneath each time a new message comes in.

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
var source=new EventSource("sse/lup.php?");
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML+=event.data;
};
}
else
{
document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent     events...";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
var source=new EventSource("sse/lup.php?");
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML= event.data + document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML;
};
}
else
{
document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent     events...";
}
</script>
```

OR paste your complete html code here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do something like...

```
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
   var html = document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("lup").innerHTML = event.data + html;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :(. When I adjusted my code to match my code it didn't display anything :(. Thanks for your help anyway it's much appreciated.